# JIRA - Is it possible to use multiple issues within the same workflow?

Tags: javascript, java, workflow, jira

I am wondering whether I can use multiple issues in a workflow or not? So the workflow in my head will be as follows: Some people in an inspection group will create an issue. They will enter some data to the JIRA system and also they will grant some authorizations to other people. Afterwards, the people who have been granted authorizations will proceed within the work flow by creating another issue? So, to sum up, can I break a workflow into different aparts such that every apart will run with different issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, these are called subtasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parent issue can have multiple child task. You can get more information about the same through this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/creating-issues-and-sub-tasks-764478439.html)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.